# How to reset to default the Photo editor that is pre-installed in elemtary os?

Tags: release-loki, applications, default

i am not a technical user.

this evening, i had to crop a photo to a custom/ specific size, so in the drop down menu (right click while on the photo) i found the custom size option, input my specs and was able to crop my photo.

but now, all my photos are cropped to that specific size and i am unable to create a drop down menu to edit the custom/ spec size.

how do i get it to go back to the default settings? so i can individually crop each photo? lesson learnt.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Right Click to a picture that you desire to associate, Open With. Then select "Other Application" (even if you see the default photo viewer there!).

Now select "Photo Viewer" and check the "Set as default" box below as you can see on this image:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply.

Comment: If it was useful to you, please mark the question as answered and vote UP. That will help others as well!

Comment: perhaps i did not word my question correctly. i was not trying to set my photo viewer as default viewer, i was asking how to reset the settings to default.

Answer (score -1):

elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki

Photos 0.2.4
(the photo viewer that came with the install of elementary os)

question about "crop"
last week i had to crop a photo to a specified size, so i set the custom size and cropped the photo. now i am unable to access the custom option, and every time i click the crop button the previous custom size is selected. i have searched google, unable to see how to reset the default settings. have tried uninstalling the app, same results. i am running out of ideas of how or who to ask for help.

please and thank you